# Index available but still unused-MySQL

Tags: mysql

We have created an index, particularly for one query, but I see that the query takes 5 to 6 secs for execution. I've tried to fetch the unused index using the below query and I noticed this index is listed in the unused indexes list. Please suggest how to get better performance for the below query.

Query where clause: `WHERE parsedjobdescription IS NOT NULL AND is_updated != 0`

Index:`KEY`idx_jobs_feed_parsedjobdescription_is_updated`(`parsedjobdescription`(700),`is_updated`)`

Unused Index: `SELECT * FROM sys.schema_unused_indexes;`

Columns: `parsedjobdescription varchar(50000) DEFAULT NULL                    is_updated tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'`

Explain of the Query:

possible_keys: idx_jobs_feed_parsedjobdescription_is_updated,idx_is_updated

key: idx_jobs_feed_parsedjobdescription_is_updated

key_len: 703

rows: 1

filtered: 50.0

Comment: The index selectivity is too low, and table scan is more effective.

Comment: @Akina The OP says it takes 5 to 6 secs for execution.  Wouldn't that be too underwhelming should a table scan is favoured over using index  ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo I doubt strongly that the amount of rows selected by `WHERE parsedjobdescription IS NOT NULL` condition is below 5-7%. And if this percent is above then the index usage is not effective. Another condition is unequiation, so we can not take it under consideration. And I think that the most part of mentioned 5-6s is data transferring time, not data selection.

Comment: I've added the explain of the query

Answer (score 0):

3 things prohibit using the two columns of your index:

- IS NOT NULL -- once you hit a range, the rest of the columns won't be used.
- is_updated != 0  -- This is also a "range".
- Index prefixing is problematic.

  ```
  INDEX(parsedjobdescription(700), ...  -- won't get past that prefix to use anything after it.
  ```

If the test were `is_updated = 1`, you could flip the index (or add another index):

```
  INDEX(is_updated, parsedjobdescription(100))
```